# Isn't BMP in opencv lossless?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am using OpenCV C++ to test gray images with BMP format.

Here is the code sample:

```
Mat img_cv = imread("test.jpg");
imwrite("aaa.bmp", img_cv);
Mat img_cv2 = imread("aaa.bmp")
```

Since BMP format is lossless img_cv and img_cv2 should be the same, but they aren't. Here is output sample, 10x10 gray image;

img_cv:

```
41 41 41 64 64 64 47 47 47 42
29 29 29 36 36 36 60 60 60 57
68 68 68 52 52 52 61 61 61 228
42 42 42 33 33 33 160 160 160 229
47 47 47 68 68 68 128 128 128 171
38 38 38 50 50 50 97 97 97 70
67 67 67 67 67 67 66 66 66 104
104 104 104 105 105 105 99 99 99 95
95 95 95 115 115 115 115 115 115 113
74 74 74 74 74 74 90 90 90 115
```

img_cv2

```
41 64 47 42 55 76 197 177 54 62
29 36 60 57 200 248 246 240 160 51
68 52 61 228 248 247 248 242 158 48
42 33 160 229 237 240 244 194 62 43
47 68 128 171 96 113 77 74 66 55
38 50 97 70 98 64 88 69 71 40
67 67 66 104 87 102 98 76 56 57
104 105 99 95 92 107 85 87 60 51
95 115 115 113 109 103 112 99 57 63
74 74 90 115 119 113 124 92 51 47
```

So am I doing something wrong or missing something when dealing with BMP format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're simply misinterpreting the binary data of the bitmaps. The source bitmap is 24 bits per pixel, whereas the new bitmap is 8 bits per pixel. Notice how on the source, each value is repeated three times. (3 times 8 bit bytes = 24 bits) If you just combine each set of three bytes into a single byte, it matches the target bitmap. You also appear to be truncating 1/3 of the binary data in the source bitmap you posted.

So this translation is lossless **only if** the source truly is completely greyscale. If OpenCV is indeed implicitly converting it from 24bpp to 8bpp, then it likely is a lossless operation.